# sparklyr spark_read_table from a specific database

Tags: r, databricks, sparklyr

My database admin has moved my tables from default to another database (named marketing).
my query below no longer works.

this is what was done.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW marketing.scv_snap AS select * from delta.`dbfs:/mnt/dataLake/xxx/xxx`;
select * from marketing.scv_snap limit 10
```

I am unable to include the 'marketing' path in the spark_read_table below; Appreciate your help

```r
spark_read_table(sc, 'scv_tbl', memory = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [tbl_change_db](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sparklyr/versions/1.6.2/topics/tbl_change_db) function to change current database:

```r
tbl_change_db(sc, "marketing")
data <- spark_read_table(sc, "scv_tbl")
```